# Is this a bug with os.date in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
$ lua -v -e "print(os.date('%l'))"
Lua 5.2.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
lua: (command line):1: bad argument #1 to 'date' (invalid conversion specifier '%l')
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'date'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: in
```

If so, where am I supposed to submit a bug report?

Comment: Where in [the documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) does it say it is a valid format specifier? Be *very* cautious when asserting "bugs" - that is, rephrase the question/issue without such language.

Comment: @user2246674 - you should rather consult reference manual, not PIL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug in Lua. `os.date` uses format, as described by `strftime` C function provided by your compiler (I mean the compiler that Lua was compiled with). It is known that some compilers (MSVC, for instance, which just outright crashes when provided with certain patterns) do not provide all patterns.

Comment: But you can compile Lua to accept other flags if you're sure your `strftime` supports them. See http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/loslib.c.html#LUA_STRFTIMEOPTIONS.